# SVN best practices - a "private" repository for devs?

Tags: svn, version-control

Does your organisation provide a private place in the SVN where devs could keep their own scripts, small tools, and other stuff they produce over the course of working on a project, but which don't necessarily belong to project itself?

Something like

```
/private
         /john.doe
         /richard.roe
```

Is this considered to be the "SVN best practices"?

What are alternatives (where do you keep your stuff)?

Comment: Using SVN in 2018 is not considered a best practice already. And different repositories for different things (not necessarily "per developer" because that has nothing to do with what the project is about) have been around forever; it seems you've already answered yourself.

Comment: This is called "shelving" in SVN and you can easily implement it in your repositories.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz read this: https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2016/7/204032-why-google-stores-billions-of-lines-of-code-in-a-single-repository/fulltext

Comment: @bahrep Unless you work at Google, that's pretty much irrelevant knowledge. And Google uses Mercurial anyway.